# Eclipse Makefile project to be built within a Cygwin environment

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

We have a project (C) (*not* a Cygwin exe project, but some embedded cross-compiled one), which has a Makefile designed to be used from within a Cygwin environment. That is the intended use is to open a Cygwin terminal, go t the project directory and run `make` from there.

I can import this project in Eclipse as a Makefile project, but apparently the regular build command from within Eclipse won't work as it is trying to invoke `make` in the native (Windows) environment. Is there a way to make Eclipse to run the Cygwin, invoke a `make` command in it and have the regular CDT error parsers to work? Perhaps by creating a custom builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work around this problem by using a build script invoking some cygwin commands:

**build.bat:**

```
@echo off
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "cd %cd:\=/%; make %*"
```

Breakdown:

`c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "<command>"` - used to invoke a command from within cygwin environment

`cd %cd:\=/%;` - is a "dos" `%cd%` variable (current path) with backslashes replaced by slashes - to avoid these to be stripped down as unescaped.

`make %*` - invoke the cygwin `make` command with all of the arguments passed to this batch file - this is to let Eclipse pass the build target and/or build flags.

Now in "project build" tab in eclipse I replace the `make` command with `build.bat` and it is working like a charm. The only drawback i to have this file in addition to the other project files, but since it is pretty generic it can be reused in any project with these restrictions.